# Return a list of search results with results related to user first with ElasticSearch or Neo4j

Tags: elasticsearch, neo4j

I'm trying to choose a database/search engine to return a list of results which shows any results the user has a relationship with first, then others after. Similar to the way Facebook works where you search a business name and one's you have liked appear first then others after?

I've seen this question which is similar to what I need but I believe it only show's results for that user: [How can ElasticSearch be used to implement social search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688977/how-can-elasticsearch-be-used-to-implement-social-search)

Is this possible with either ElasticSearch, Neo4j or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch can certainly do this.

Results are returned from Elasticsearch based on the score, which basically means the better the match the bigger the score.

You could use the "bool" query to specify your query as a "must" and then the user match as a "should". Optionally you might want to add a "boost" to the should query so it scores highest if matched.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html